# Binding Click method in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-8

In Windows 8, C# + xaml
i have some class

```
Class ABC
{
 public string a {get; set;}
 public void someMethod()
 {
  **some code, changing a**
 }
}
```

and binding in xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="playlistBox">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding a}"/>
                     <Button Name="removeAlbumBtn" Content="method" Click="**NEED BINDING TO SOMEMETHOD HERE**"/>
                </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

So what i must type to call someMethod???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the `Click` event through a handler method in the *code behind* of that xaml file. For example, if the xaml you show is in a `MyControl.xaml`. You'll have a method like the following in the `MyControl.xaml.cs`:

```
private void removeAlbumBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var a = ((Button)sender).DataContext as ABC;

    if(a != null)
        a.someMethod();
}
```

And change the xaml to be:

```
<Button Name="removeAlbumBtn" Content="method" Click="removeAlbumBtn_Click"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using commands. But the amount of work you have to do is a bit more than just writing a method to bind it. This post on commands in WPF and Silverlight might help you in understanding and implementing commands: http://tsells.wordpress.com/2010/06/23/command-binding-with-wpf-and-silverlight-net-4-0-with-m-v-vm/

It will work on Windows 8 also, as it is a feature of XAML.